# How to get spring scheduled task List with their Trigger info?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

In my spring boot app, i am creating scheduled task programatically e.g

```
@Configuration
 @EnableScheduling
 public class AppConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

     @Override
     public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
         taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskScheduler());   

         //following loop will get executed according to requirement for now //just looping 0-9
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
         MyRunnable myRunnable=new MyRunnable();
         myRunnable.setID(i);
         taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(myRunnable,new CronTrigger("0 0/15 * * * *"));
       }
     }

     @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
     public Executor taskScheduler() {
         return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(42);
     }

     @Bean
     public MyTask myTask() {
         return new MyTask();
     }
 }
```

I need some way to reschedule above task on the fly,can some one help me to complete above work? i would prefer rescheduling task by ID like **myRunnable.getID()**.
Any help would be highly appreciated?

i have tried following in my Controller

```
@Autowired 
private ScheduledTaskRegistrar  scheduledTaskRegistrar;
```

But it is not injecting in controller

Comment: Is it web application? Does it use any storage?

Comment: yes i am storing in DB

Comment: @AniketKulkarni how were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Divs Now i am using Quartz for this

Comment: how do you solve it now？